# Foreign key (FK300D262149997B:four [three_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (three [one_id,two_id])

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, mapping

Target :
    am trying to understand hibernate mappings. when i try the mapping tables i got an error like

Foreign key (FK300D262149997B:four [three_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (three [one_id,two_id])

Hibernate mapping :

```
1). Created table 'one' with two columns (primary key and name field).
2). Created table 'two' with two columns (primary key and name field).
3). Created table 'three' with three columns (primary key, foreign key reference of table 'one' and foreign key reference of table 'two').
4). Created table 'four' with three columns (primary key, foreign key reference of table 'three' and name field).
5). Entity class 'One' has the set of 'Two' class.
```

Problem :

```
When mapping is compiled am getting following error. 

Foreign key (FK300D262149997B:four [three_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (three [one_id,two_id])
```

Attached sources :

DDL :

```
CREATE TABLE ONE(
id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
NAME VARCHAR(45));

CREATE TABLE two(
id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
NAME VARCHAR(45));

CREATE TABLE three(
id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
one_id BIGINT,
two_id BIGINT,
KEY `one_id` (`one_id`),
KEY `two_id` (`two_id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_one_three` FOREIGN KEY (`one_id`) REFERENCES `one` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_two_three` FOREIGN KEY (`two_id`) REFERENCES `two` (`id`) );

CREATE TABLE four(
id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
three_id BIGINT,
NAME VARCHAR(45),
KEY `three_id` (`three_id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_three_four` FOREIGN KEY (`three_id`) REFERENCES `three` (`id`));
```

Entity :

One.java

```
public class One {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Two> twos;

    public Set<Two> getTwos() {
        return twos;
    }
    public void setTwos(Set<Two> twos) {
        this.twos = twos;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Two.java

```
public class Two {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Three.java

```
public class Three {
    private long id;
    private One one;
    private Two two;
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public One getOne() {
        return one;
    }
    public void setOne(One one) {
        this.one = one;
    }
    public Two getTwo() {
        return two;
    }
    public void setTwo(Two two) {
        this.two = two;
    }   
}
```

Four.java

```
public class Four {
    private long id;
    private Three three;
    private String name;
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Three getThree() {
        return three;
    }
    public void setThree(Three three) {
        this.three = three;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

How can I make this to work?

Comment: Take a look at following link it may help you


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510547/hibernate-issue-foreign-key-must-have-same-number-of-columns-as-referenced-pri

Comment: referred. but they have different hibernate mappings with no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is telling that your table contains a foreign key on a column  but your referenced table  defines it's primary key with two columns , which by the way is very common for relationship tables.

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579449/foreign-key-must-have-same-number-of-columns-as-the-reference-primary-key-hibern) for details

Comment: Yes. then how will be the relationship look like (ddl)?

Comment: you need to map composite primary key in mapping files

Comment: If we map composite primary key, how the table 'three' will refer on table 'four' (see the table structure and entity).